# MySQL Basic Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, connection

I have a MySQL table called connections, with two unsigned integer fields, called a and b (which are unique), with the following values (and many more).

> A, B
>   1, 2
>   1, 3
>   8, 9
>   4, 6
>   5, 1
>   3, 7

1 is connected to 2, 3, and 5. 3 is connected to 7. I have been struggling to come up with a query that will select all connections for a given number. For example, number 2 would return the following...

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   5
>   7

Number 5 would also return...

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   5
>   7

If someone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it. I have been stuck on this for the last week, and have made little to no progress. :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your problem cannot be solved with a single select statement. Solution requires multipass scan of your tables to arrive at the final answer

Comment: Argh!  Why is this downvoted?  +1!  The solution will need looping / cursor / recursive constructs (or a recursive CTE in SQL Server).

Comment: Can you give me a PHP example, please?

Comment: Not only has it been downvoted, it has also been flagged as spam. Someone's got an axe to grind.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a hierarchical query here, which exists in Oracle, but I don't think it is in mySql.  Here is a link to an article which explains how to get hierarchical functionality in mySql.  I have not tried it myself.

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: This is not even related to this topic. I assume that you responded to the wrong question? Thanks though.

Comment: I though I understood the question, but maybe not.  Are you trying to take, for example B=2, and then follow its relations?  if so, then it matches items with A=1, which are itself, and the 1,3 pair.  And then do you want to follow 1 and 3 separately?  If so then, that would add the 5,1 pair and 3,7 pair, and that would be all.  It sounds like a hierarchical query to me.  But please let me know if I am completely missing the point.